# Wordpress add rewrite rule to point to plugin file

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Firstly, I have tried several different suggestions from other stackoverflow users but I haven't had any luck.

I'm trying to build a kind of api from inside a plugin. The task is to let an external system call a URL within my plugin in order for it to initiate an internal procedure.

Currently I have a class which has a contructor. This is inside that constructor.

```
add_action( 'init', 'my_rewrite' );
function my_rewrite() {
  global $wp_rewrite;

  $plugin_url = plugins_url( 'my-api.php', __FILE__ );
  $plugin_url = substr( $plugin_url, strlen( home_url() ) + 1 );

  add_rewrite_rule('/my-api/(.*)', $plugin_url ,'top');

  $wp_rewrite->flush_rules(true);
}
```

This then generates a RewriteRule in my htaccess file.

```
RewriteRule ^/my-api/(.*) /wp-content/plugins/my-api/classes/my-api.php [QSA,L]
```

Below is the whole .htaccess file for context

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^/slurp-api/(.*) /wp-content/plugins/slurp/classes/my-api.php [QSA,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

For whatever reason when I visit site.dev/my-api I see a 404 page rather than the echo statement that should run from my-api.php

The dev site is being run through mamp pro if that is any help.

Any pointers as to why this rewrite isn't playing fair would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: If you are using these rules in htaccess context, then..try removing the leading slash from all ruleS, RewriteRule **/** myapi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after much tinkering I came upon the correct answer.
I changed this line to

```
add_rewrite_rule('my-api', $plugin_url ,'top');
```

I tried many variations on this but this one finally worked. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the leading forward slash from the original request

```
RewriteRule ^my-api/(.*) /wp-content/plugins/my-api/classes/my-api.php [QSA,L]
```

And make sure the file `my-api.php` exists at the location you give in the rewrite target:

```
/wp-content/plugins/my-api/classes/my-api.php
```

So as not to intentionally give it a non-existent target.

As @Starkeen mentions in the comments, you can remove the leading forward slash from the target also, like this

```
RewriteRule ^my-api/(.*) wp-content/plugins/my-api/classes/my-api.php [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have removed the leading slashes, the line now looks like this. RewriteRule ^my-api/(.*) wp-content/plugins/my-api/classes/my-api.php [QSA,L].  Interestingly I can browse to the api file by going to site.dev/wp-content/plugins/my-api/classes/my-api.php This works perfectly.

Comment: Sorry, I hit return before I finished typing the comment. No the changes haven't worked. Thanks

Comment: go to this url, `http://site.dev/my-api/something-nice` and check if it's working or not

Comment: Ideally I'd like Wordpress to handle the rule creation since it is a plugin I really don't/shouldn't have access to the htaccess file.

Comment: That URL doesnt work. I've tried everything I can think of.