# Add Rewrite Rules

Tags: wordpress, url-rewriting

I'm trying to write a rewrite rule (as opposed to just copying my files to the root folder) in my wordpress theme.

```
add_action("init",function(){
    add_rewrite_rule( '^manifest.json' , "wp-content/themes/dist/manifest.json" , 'top' );
    flush_rewrite_rules();
});
```

But it doesn't seem to be working. any tips? It keeps resulting in redirection to the 404 page.

Comment: Can you access the manifest.json file by directly inputting the URL ("wp-content/themes/dist/manifest.json")?

Comment: @klumme yes I can

Answer (score 0):

You're adding a rewrite rule to WordPress, not the file system. Therefore, the request you're rewriting will still attempt to be handled by WordPress. Therefore, you're going to get a 404, as WordPress doesn't have any content that matches that request.

You'll probably want to instead add a 301 redirect to your .htaccess file instead. This fires before WordPress, and is probably the faster way to do this anyways.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Greg. So is there no way to get this "self contained" within my theme? Without having to either copy the file to my root or modifying the .htaccess? (or in my current workaround, making a symlink)

Comment: It seems like the OP here can access a file (not a route)

https://stackoverflow.com/a/34156716/2873337

I'll have to look into it a bit more.

Comment: Hmm.. That's interesting -- The OP there claims that his rewrite rules in WP populated out to the htaccess file. I don't think this typically happens.. I've seen a plugin like WordFence that uses some code to go out and edit the contents of an .htaccess file directly, adding in redirect rules,etc. Here's some code from their plugin that may be of help if you decide to go that route: https://github.com/wp-plugins/wordfence/blob/2bce197c365767614ceeddcd1a94b2a0bb919883/lib/wfCache.php#L431

Comment: Thanks @Greg. I'll look into it. Though from the .htaccess rule, if a file exists, it will serve it before redirecting to the WordPress index.php. 

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

If the add_rewrite_rule simply does a header redirect, then it should pass through the whole browser load process won't it?